# Is Java floating arithmetic division always within 1 ULP of the true result?

Tags: java, math, floating-point

Is Java's floating arithmetic division always within 1 ULP of the true result? I read that CPUs sometimes do floating-point division `a/b` by doing `a * 1/b`. However, `1/b` may be off by 1 ULP, and multiplication adds up to 1 ULP of error. Doesn't this mean that the final error could be 2 ULPs?

This doesn't sound right to me, because I know there are many methods in the Math class that are within 1 ULP of the true result (such as Math.pow), so I don't think something as simple as division would be less accurate.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [*JEP 306: Restore Always-Strict Floating-Point Semantics*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/306)

Comment: Re “I read that CPUs sometimes do floating-point division `a/b` by doing `a * 1/b`”: No, they do not. No mainstream CPU does this. Maybe there is some low-end special-purpose processor that does that. And, when you are reporting something you read, give a citation. That provides us with context we can use to interpret and check the statement or to report an error back to the author. Where did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4 contains Java's specifications on this.  The relevant clause is probably this one:

> The Java programming language requires that floating-point arithmetic behave as if every floating-point operator rounded its floating-point result to the result precision. Inexact results must be rounded to the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result; if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero is chosen. This is the IEEE 754 standard's default rounding mode known as round to nearest.

I read this as 1/2 ULP precision: the two nearest values are one ulp apart, and Java chooses "the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result," i.e. the closer one, which must be within 1/2 ULP.